# ElasticSearch Service - Centos 7 - How to view console

Tags: command-line, elasticsearch, centos, kibana, centos7

So I have successfully installed and started ElasticSearch as a service in Centos 7. My question is this. After the service is started, is there a way to view the console that one would see if it didn't start ElasticSearch as a service?

An example of the console I am trying to see is below:(This is what it would have looked like if I didn't start it as a service).

[image: Elastic Search - When Starting Normally]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have started elasticsearch on console, you can check whether elasticsearch is running or not by entering following url in browser:
http://localhost:9200

By entering above url if you get a response such as:

```
{
 "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Doppelganger",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "62ff9868b4c8a0c45860bebb259e21980778ab1c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-04-27T09:21:06Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

It means your elasticsearch is working.

Note: If you are not running elasticsearch instance & enter the url you will find **webpage is not available message.**